# Find Visible Child Window

Tags: wpf

I want to search any visible child window with this simple code but Message keep saying Window not found. Can anyone has an idea about searching visible child window in main window?

Here's the code:

```
private HomeWindow NewHomeWindow = new HomeWindow();
string ReturnWindowName;
private void btnhome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReturnWindowName = "NewHomeWindow";
    NewHomeWindow.Owner = this;
    NewHomeWindow.Show();
}

private void btnsearchwindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ChangeWindow();
}

public void ChangeWindow()
{
    Window mySearchWindow = (Window)this.FindName(ReturnWindowName);

    if (mySearchWindow != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Window Found");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Window Not Found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are assigning ownership to your Windows, can you make use of the [OwnedWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.ownedwindows) Property to iterate through the Parents Owned Windows to find the one you are looking for? In further looking at your code you are creating a class level variable named `NewHomeWindow` you are not assigning anything to the `Name` Property, [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname) is searching for a child element, not an owned window. If you add a Name to your Window and use something like this you should be able to locate it.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private HomeWindow NewHomeWindow = new HomeWindow(); 
    string ReturnWindowName;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NewHomeWindow.Name="NewHomeWindow";
    }

    private void btnhome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        ReturnWindowName = "NewHomeWindow";
        NewHomeWindow.Owner = this;
        NewHomeWindow.Show();
    }

    private void btnsearchwindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeWindow(); 
    }

    public void ChangeWindow()
    {
        foreach (Window w in this.OwnedWindows)
        {
            if (w.Name == ReturnWindowName)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Window Found");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Window Not Found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your question, but I think you're wanting to find the visual child of a control?

This is a helper function that I use frequently..

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>( DependencyObject depObj ) where T : DependencyObject
        {
           if( depObj != null )
           {
              for( int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount( depObj ); i++ )
              {
                 DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild( depObj, i );
                 if( child != null && child is T )
                 {
                    yield return (T)child;
                 }

                 foreach( T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>( child ) )
                 {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

In your example, you'd look for a window:

```
foreach (var window in FindVisualChildren<Window>(this))
{
  if (window.ReturnWindowName == <insertNameHere>)
     return window;
}
```

From there, you can loop through the windows found and match the name.